# What code to I need to add to cut off text after 3 lines and add ellipses in Wordpress website?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I'm having a problem on my Wordpress website (buenavistamag.com), which was built using Elementor and a paid theme called NeoTech. In the sliding thumbnail carousel on the front page, the long article titles keep making the carousel very large on mobile which is causing the carousel to interfere with the large title text. Is it possible to cut off the titles in the carousel (not the big title, only the thumbnail titles in the carousel) after 3 lines and add and ellipses to the end? If possible, can you cut it off only after a space so that words don't get cut off mid-word? Lastly, will this solve my problem where the carousel is interfering with the featured article's main title? If you're confused as to what I'm talking about, please tell me so I can clarify. I tried attaching images, but I have no place to host them and create a link to them.

I don't code, so the only solutions I've tried have been changing numbers related to the slider, which I believe is labeled as the 'Hero Slider' in the CSS style sheet style.css. I have had no luck. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your themes css file

```
    .hero__slide-thumb-text-holder div h2 a {
   display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: your CSS is working, but it's shortening the wrong title (see buenavistamag.com). Can you change the code so that it shortens the text in the sliding carousel and not the big title?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it! I was trying to shorten .carousel-thumbs__title and not .hero__slide-thumb-text-holder. I took your css and added it to the .carousel-thumbs__title text formatting and its working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `-webkit-line-clamp`

```css
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-clamp">Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
```

**Note:** This will work on modern browsers only

Comment: are there other vendor prefixed versions of `-webkit-line-clamp` for other browsers ?

Comment: No. it will support latest browses only:

Comment: @Vikas Jadhav where do I put this code? Also, will this affect all text on my website or just the text in my sliding carousel?

Comment: @shaansridhar put this code into your css file and this will affect only element with class .line-clamp